# apply ifelse to multiple columns and create new column

Tags: r, apply, categories

I have a data frame with 4 columns that contain job titles. For each column, I want to create a new column (category1, category2, category3, category4) which assign each job a category 1-10 depending on which words the job titles contain (e.g. if the job title contains the words "frontend", "ui", "ux" then the column category1 should say 1). I managed to do the categorizing manually for each column using the following code but want to do it at the same time for all 4 columns. Any help is appreciated!

```
data_rel$category1 <-
ifelse(grepl("frontend|ui|ux", data$job4_clean),1, ifelse(grepl("backend", data$job4_clean),2, ifelse(grepl("fullstack", data$job4_clean),3, ifelse(grepl("entwickler|development|application|developer|software",data$job4_clean),4, ifelse(grepl("data|analytics|machine|programmer|ml|engineer|engineering|programmer|learning",data$job4_clean),5, ifelse(grepl("research|teaching|akademischer|researcher",data$job4_clean),6, ifelse(grepl("project|manager|product|consultant|consulting",data$job4_clean),7, ifelse(grepl("it|security|technical|tech", data$job4_clean),8, ifelse(grepl("margketing|sales|media|saas|business|commerce|support|development|digital|markeing|graphic|designer|graphics|design",data$job4_clean),9, ifelse(grepl("founder|ceo|partner|chief|executive|cto",data$job4_clean),10,NA))))))))))
```

```
data_rel <- structure(list(job1 = c("phd fellow", "java developer intern", 
"optical engineer", " dwh bi engineer", " software engineer", 
"software developer", "data engineer", "application software engineer", 
"software developer", " web developer", "web developer", "web developer", 
"software engineer", "software engineer", " es computer", "associate software engineer", 
"fullstack ios developer", "technical delivery manager project manager", 
"software architect", "software developer"), job2 = c("research scientist", 
"analytics analyst", " developer", " data ml engineer", "graduate teaching assistant", 
"software developer", "machine learning engineer", "akademischer mitarbeiter machine learning and analytics", 
"backend develope", "lead php developer", "php system analytic software specialist", 
"webcreater", "data engineer", "software engineer", "assistant network administrator", 
"frontend engineer", "application infrastructor lead", "software engineer", 
"application developer", "software developer"), job3 = c("data scientist", 
"machine learning engineer", "application developer associate manager", 
NA, "co founder cto", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "lead php sugarcrm developer", 
" php developer", "data analysing researcher ", NA, "application developer consultance", 
"manager l1 ui frontend ", " software architect", "software engineering manager solution architect", 
"software developer consultance", "ai developer"), job4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "software architect development lead", 
"team leader", NA, NA, " application development specialist", 
" associate experience technology", NA, " software developer", 
"fullstack developer productowner", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Convert your ifelse into a function... `foo <- function(x){ ifelse(x....)}` then loop through columns `lapply(myData[, c("col1", "col2", etc)], foo)`

Comment: Read about `switch` function, too, to avoid nested ifelse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function with `case_when` -

```
library(dplyr)

change_category <- function(x) {
  case_when(grepl("frontend|ui|ux", x) ~ 1L, 
            grepl("backend", x) ~ 2L, 
            grepl("fullstack", x) ~ 3L, 
            grepl("entwickler|development|application|developer|software",x) ~ 4L, 
            grepl("data|analytics|machine|programmer|ml|engineer|engineering|programmer|learning",x) ~5L,
            grepl("research|teaching|akademischer|researcher",x) ~ 6L, 
            grepl("project|manager|product|consultant|consulting", x) ~ 7L, 
            grepl("it|security|technical|tech", x) ~ 8L, 
            grepl("margketing|sales|media|saas|business|commerce|support|development|digital|markeing|graphic|designer|graphics|design",x) ~ 9L, 
            grepl("founder|ceo|partner|chief|executive|cto",x) ~10L)
}
```

and apply it with `across` -

```
data_rel %>% mutate(across(.fns = change_category, .names = '{col}_category'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @zx8754's comment, you can put your code in a function, use `lapply` to apply to each column, and finish up with `do.call` to combine the columns as a `data.frame` again.

```
get_level <- function(col) {
  ifelse(grepl("frontend|ui|ux", col), 1, 
    ifelse(grepl("backend", col), 2,
      ifelse(grepl("fullstack", col), 3, 
        ifelse(grepl("entwickler|development|application|developer|software",col), 4, 
          ifelse(grepl("data|analytics|machine|programmer|ml|engineer|engineering|programmer|learning",col), 5, 
            ifelse(grepl("research|teaching|akademischer|researcher",col), 6, 
              ifelse(grepl("project|manager|product|consultant|consulting",col), 7, 
                ifelse(grepl("it|security|technical|tech", col), 8, 
                  ifelse(grepl("margketing|sales|media|saas|business|commerce|support|development|digital|markeing|graphic|designer|graphics|design", col), 9, 
                    ifelse(grepl("founder|ceo|partner|chief|executive|cto", col), 10,
                      NA))))))))))
}

cats <- lapply(data_rel, get_level)
cats <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, cats)
names(cats) <- paste0("category", seq_along(data_rel))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map_dfc` from `purrr` package to iterate over each column of our data set detecting the category and bind the resulting column column-wise. I used `case_when` instead of `ifelse` for a slightly nicer-looked output:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data_rel %>%
  map_dfc(~ case_when(
    grepl("frontend|ui|ux", .x) ~ 1, 
    grepl("backend", .x) ~ 2,
    grepl("fullstack", .x) ~ 3,
    grepl("entwickler|development|application|developer|software", .x) ~ 4,
    grepl("data|analytics|machine|programmer|ml|engineer|engineering|programmer|learning", .x) ~ 5,
    grepl("research|teaching|akademischer|researcher", .x) ~ 6, 
    grepl("project|manager|product|consultant|consulting", .x) ~ 7,
    grepl("it|security|technical|tech", .x) ~ 8,
    grepl("margketing|sales|media|saas|business|commerce|support|development|digital|markeing|graphic|designer|graphics|design", .x) ~ 9,
    grepl("founder|ceo|partner|chief|executive|cto", .x) ~ 10,
    TRUE ~ as.numeric(NA)
  ))

# A tibble: 20 x 4
    job1  job2  job3  job4
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1    NA     6     5    NA
 2     4     5     5    NA
 3     5     4     4    NA
 4     5     5    NA    NA
 5     4     6    10    NA
 6     4     4    NA    NA
 7     5     5    NA    NA
 8     4     5    NA    NA
 9     4     2    NA    NA
10     4     4    NA    NA
11     4     4     4     4
12     4    NA     4    NA
13     4     5     5    NA
14     4     4    NA    NA
15    NA    NA     4     4
16     4     1     1     8
17     3     4     4    NA
18     7     4     4     4
19     4     4     4     3
20     4     4     4    NA
```

or in base R:

```
cbind(sapply(data_rel, function(x) {
  ifelse(grepl("frontend|ui|ux", x),1, 
         ifelse(grepl("backend", x),2, 
                ifelse(grepl("fullstack", x),3, 
                       ifelse(grepl("entwickler|development|application|developer|software", x),4, 
                              ifelse(grepl("data|analytics|machine|programmer|ml|engineer|engineering|programmer|learning", x),5, 
                                     ifelse(grepl("research|teaching|akademischer|researcher", x),6, 
                                            ifelse(grepl("project|manager|product|consultant|consulting", x),7, 
                                                   ifelse(grepl("it|security|technical|tech", x),8, 
                                                          ifelse(grepl("margketing|sales|media|saas|business|commerce|support|development|digital|markeing|graphic|designer|graphics|design", x),9, 
                                                                 ifelse(grepl("founder|ceo|partner|chief|executive|cto", x),10,NA))))))))))
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the jobs in a vector an then iterate over them with `sapply` using `grepl` and `match` to get the job numbers.

```
jobs <- c("frontend|ui|ux"
        , "backend"
        , "fullstack"
        , "entwickler|development|application|developer|software"
        , "data|analytics|machine|programmer|ml|engineer|engineering|programmer|learning"
        , "research|teaching|akademischer|researcher"
        , "project|manager|product|consultant|consulting"
        , "it|security|technical|tech"
        , "margketing|sales|media|saas|business|commerce|support|development|digital|markeing|graphic|designer|graphics|design"
        , "founder|ceo|partner|chief|executive|cto")

sapply(data_rel, function(x) apply(sapply(jobs, grepl, x), 1, match, x=TRUE))
#      job1 job2 job3 job4
# [1,]   NA    6    5   NA
# [2,]    4    5    5   NA
# [3,]    5    4    4   NA
# [4,]    5    5   NA   NA
# [5,]    4    6   10   NA
# [6,]    4    4   NA   NA
# [7,]    5    5   NA   NA
# [8,]    4    5   NA   NA
# [9,]    4    2   NA   NA
#[10,]    4    4   NA   NA
#[11,]    4    4    4    4
#[12,]    4   NA    4   NA
#[13,]    4    5    5   NA
#[14,]    4    4   NA   NA
#[15,]   NA   NA    4    4
#[16,]    4    1    1    8
#[17,]    3    4    4   NA
#[18,]    7    4    4    4
#[19,]    4    4    4    3
#[20,]    4    4    4   NA
```